# Plotting CPU and Ram utilization

Tags: raspbian, memory, cpu, process, gnuplot

I want to plot the CPU and memory utilisation of an Apache server hosted in Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian Stretch in it. For that I have followed the procedure mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/monitoring-process-memorycpu-usage-with-top-and-pl). The instructions work fine in a Ubuntu Desktop with the modification, `top -p $PID -bn 1` in place of `top -p $PID -bMn 1` in *monitor-usage.sh* file. But using the same in Raspberry Pi, it fails to extract the CPU and memory info. On further studying, I found out that the instruction, `egrep '^[0-9]+'` is not working in Raspberry Pi. What could be the possible reason? And how can I achieve my goal if I have to find any alternative?

Comment: What is the error message related to the `egrep '^[0-9]+'` command?

Comment: In Buster I do not see an error when the 'M' is removed from the `top` but the output file does not have the memory with m/g suffix - I also cannot see the **M** in the top manual for Ubuntu... To make matters worse the github does not exist.  Does egrep exist in Stretch?  I have no Stretch box handy.

Comment: Apache has some built-in statistics you can enable see [server-status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html).

Comment: @justinjt, @Andyroo it doesn't show any error or as such. Just goes back to the prompt. In fact a `man egrep` takes me to manual page of `grep`. I tried replacing it with `grep` as well, but didn't work.

Comment: @meuh. Thank you. I will note that down but would like to pursue the above as well. If it works, it will help in plotting for other processes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`egrep` is just a shell script that runs `grep -E`. `grep`, `egrep`, and `fgrep` are a family of commands that share the same binary and man page. Your egrep is probably finding nothing because it is trying to match a number at the start of the line (the process id) in the output from `top`, but instead there are spaces in front of the number.

The article you link to must be using a different version of top to you, with slight differences in output. This is not untypical for commands that are meant to be used interactively. Nonetheless, I used the following command on my Raspberry Pi to get the wanted data:

```
#!/bin/bash
top -p "${1?pid}" -b -d 1 |
awk '$1~/[0-9]/{print systime(),$6,$9;fflush()}' > top.dat
```

I've simplified the code: instead of a while loop, `top` runs continuously with an interval of 1 second (`-d 1`). Instead of `egrep`, `awk` looks for a number (`[0-9]`) in the first column (`$1`) of the output. Instead of `date`, `awk` uses its built-in `systime()` function.  The output of awk is buffered, so when you interrupt the script to stop it, a lot of data that hasn't yet been written to the file can be lost. The `fflush()` avoids this.

If this doesn't work for you, try replacing `awk` by `gawk`. You may need to install gawk. (A simpler minimal awk may have been installed by default).

Note that the script is collecting columns 6 (`$6`) and 9. You may need or want to change this depending on the `top` output. My version shows these headers:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
```

so `$6` is `RES` which is the resident memory usage. `$5` might be more appropriate, the total virtual memory.  Both these values are in kibibytes (*1024) and do not seem to get `m` and `g` suffixes as in the linked article. To get around this I changed the gnuplot script `usage-plot.gp` to replace

```
check(x)=(real(resolveUnits(x)))
```

by

```
check(x)=(real(x)*1024)
```

I also changed the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -c
```

as I couldn't get gnuplot to accept `-preview` with `-c`. You may not need to do this.